# How to Get iso code from using Dial code , intlTelInput jQueryPlugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I get iso code from dial code using intlTelInput.

This is my form

```
<input type="text" name="mobile_no" id="mobile_no" value="{{$user->phone}}">
<input type="text" id="country_code" name="country_code" value="{{$user->country_code}}">
<input type="text" id="mobile_nos" name="mobile_nos" value="<?php echo $user->country_code.$user->phone; ?>">
```

For example values will be $user->phone :9*455******, $user->country_code: 91 and $user->country_code.$user->phone; will be 919***455*****

I have tried this code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var userCountryCode = $("#country_code").val(); 
        alert(userCountryCode);
        var countryData = $("#mobile_nos").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData"); // alert(countryData);
       var isoCode = countryData.iso; alert(isoCode);


        $("#mobile_no").intlTelInput({
            initialCountry: isoCode,
            separateDialCode: true,
            autoPlaceholder: "aggressive",
        });

        $("#mobile_no").on("countrychange", function () {
            var selectedCountryData = $("#mobile_no").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData");
            var selectedCountryCode = selectedCountryData.dialCode;
            document.querySelector("#country_code").value = selectedCountryCode;
        });
    });
</script>
```

But result alert is undefined